# How to toggle Switch Widget on Bottom Modal Popup?

Tags: flutter

I have a very simple Flutter project in which there are 2 switches:

- First switch (isImportant1) is on the home page, and it works great.  When I select it, it updates the screen perfectly.
- Second switch (isImportant2) on a modal bottom sheet does not work the way I want it to.  It does not update the screen when I click it.  However, I do believe it's updating the value properly behind the scenes.
- These are not tied together. I don't want them to effect each other.
- I just want the widget to update on the screen when my user clicks them.

Photos at bottom after code.  Thank you for your time!

How can I get the second switch on the modal popup to update?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Future<void> _showModal() async {

    bool isImportant2 = false;
    void toggleImportant2(bool value) {
      setState(() {
        isImportant2 = value;
      });
    }

    await showModalBottomSheet(
        isScrollControlled: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20,
                left: 20,
                right: 20,
                // prevent the soft keyboard from covering text fields
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(ctx).viewInsets.bottom + 20),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                const Text("Important: "),
                Switch(
                  value: isImportant2,
                  onChanged: (value) { toggleImportant2(value); },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
  
  bool isImportant1 = false;
  void toggleImportant1(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      isImportant1 = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            const Text("Important: "),
            Switch(
              value: isImportant1,
              onChanged: (value) { toggleImportant1(value); },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _showModal(),
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: First Switch on Home Page updates perfectly]

[image: Second Switch on Bottom Modal Popup does not update screen]

Comment: you're doing it wrong. your show modlabuttomsheet function should return boolean that you should store in a variable. `final bottomSheet = showModalBottomSheet();  setState(()=> important2 = bottomSheet);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seperate your bottom sheet to a statefulwidget and it will work, like this:

```
class BottomSheetSwitch extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _BottomSheetSwitchState createState() => _BottomSheetSwitchState();
}

class _BottomSheetSwitchState extends State<BottomSheetSwitch> {
  bool isImportant2 = false;
  void toggleImportant2(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      isImportant2 = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 20,
          left: 20,
          right: 20,
          // prevent the soft keyboard from covering text fields
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 20),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          const Text("Important: "),
          Switch(
            value: isImportant2,
            onChanged: (value) { toggleImportant2(value); },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then in your main.dart, call :

```
  Future<void> _showModal() async {
    await showModalBottomSheet(
        isScrollControlled: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
          return BottomSheetSwitch();
        });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and code. That worked perfectly. I need to start separating more widgets.